# Count of nulls and non-nulls in one Teradata query

Tags: sql, teradata

in mySQL if I was looking to find the sum of null and non-null values for a column in one query, I can use

```
SELECT 
SUM(col IS NOT NULL),
SUM(col IS NULL)
FROM test
```

However, the same syntax doesn't work in Teradata (Syntax error: expected something between the word 'col' and the 'IS' keyword.)

How can I adapt the above logic to Teradata?

Comment: Is CASE syntax allowed?

Comment: @Strawberry I was hoping to just keep it to booleans but I'd take something that worked. I played around with it but couldn't get it to work. Have you got an example of any working code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CASE`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN col IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN col IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM test;
```

Or, use `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(col),
       COUNT(*) - COUNT(col)
FROM test;
```

Both of these are standard SQL and will work in any database.

Comment: Boom! Thanks Gordon.